# New function added in WCF service is not showing on Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, windows-phone-8.1, wcf-data-services

I have a simple web application on Asp.net MVC. I created a WFC Service so I can get data to my Windows 8.1 app, but my new functions are not showing in my client side.

This My WFC code:

```
[DataContract]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        ApplicationDbContext _db=new ApplicationDbContext();

        public string GetData(int value)
        {


            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public WtFImages.Models.Images GetDataL(int value)
        {
            var User = _db.Image.Local.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == value);

            return User;
        }
        public List<WtFImages.Models.Images> GetDataAll(int value)
        {
            var GetAllPublic = _db.Image.Local.ToList();

            return (GetAllPublic);
        }

        public IList<WtFImages.Models.Images> ZGetDataAll(int value)
        {
            var GetAllPublic = _db.Image.Local.ToList();

            return (GetAllPublic);
        }
        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
}
```

My client side only shows the default functions.

[image]

Iservice Code

```
namespace ImageFechingWfc
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }


    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each method that you want to expose as service method, should exists in you `IService1` interface and should be decorated with [`[OperationContract]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), then you should implement that method in service class.

- Open `IService1.cs` and put signature of your methods is `IService1` interface then decorate your new methods with `[OperationContract]`, then put implementations in `Service1` and rebuild the project, then add your service reference and use it.
- Also You don't need that `[DataContract]` above your service implementation.

For example if you want to have an `int Add(int x, int y)` method in your service, put this in your `IService1` interface:

```
[OperationContract]
int Add(int x, int y);
```

and then put this in your `Service1` class:

```
public int Add(int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}
```

To learn more about WCF services, you can read this [Getting Started Tutorials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712(v=vs.110).aspx)

- [How to: Define a Windows Communication Foundation Service Contract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731835(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [How to: Implement a Windows Communication Foundation Service Contract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734686(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [How to: Host and Run a Basic Windows Communication Foundation Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730935(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [How to: Create a Windows Communication Foundation Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [How to: Configure a Basic Windows Communication Foundation Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734663(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [How to: Use a Windows Communication Foundation Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730144(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @user1157944 Yes you can do everything with `Web API`, but why do you think you will not experience problems in `Web API`. Each one of them that you want to use, you should learn more about it :)

Comment: I posted Iservice Code also actually i have no experience in WFC or Web APi :(

Comment: @user1157944 As obvious in your codes, you haven't defined your methods in the interface. To publish a method as a service method, you should add the method signature to your `IService` interface and decorate it with `[DataContract]`.

Comment: May be rebuild your wcf project

Comment: @Developer The main problem is the OP has not declared his new methods in `IService` interface ;)

Comment: @Reza completely agree with you.As OP has already done what you have suggested.Still he is saying it is not working.So justified my comment

Comment: @Developer The OP copied interface codes after I suggest to add `[OpretaionContract]` to method declarations. Since it is obvious that the method declarations doesn't exist in `IService1`, it seems "I tried i change it but not working" means the OP has no idea about WCF and needs to read more about WCF :)

Comment: @Developer And thank you for your comment, hope someone find the answer helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that your methods are listed in wsdl or not ifnot then open the visual studio as administrator account and open from Visual C# Project File not Visual Studio Project User Options file (.user).